# PHP: CSV to array Stores value into array, shows in print_r, empty when accessed

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, import

I am tasked with updating a new site with the old sites data. So importing csv to a custom post type.

I have the import working, but unfortunately the javascript side is not playing nice with csv columns that contain html.

To remedy the issue, i found that my parsing function doesn't have any issues with the html columns. Now the error happens to be, my first key of the array doesn't preserve its data. Never seen this before, kinda mind blowing. Let me know if you seen this before and how to fix it. It happens on every row too, doesn't return an artkey.

First my wordpress/php code for parsing the csv

```
function waw_article_csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
  {

      // this is an important setting!
     ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);


  // IF the file doesn't exist or the file is not readable return false
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    // setup our return data  
    $return_data = array();

    // IF we can open and read the file
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {

      $row = 0;

      // while data exists loop over data
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
          // count the number of items in this data
          $num = count($data);
          // loop over all items and append them to our row data
          for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
              // if this is the first row set it up as our header
              if( $row == 0):
                $header[] = $data[$c];
              else:
                  // all rows greater than 1
                  //add to $return_data
                  $return_data[$row-1][$header[$c]] = $data[$c];
              endif;
          }
          $row++;
      } 

      // close our file
      fclose($handle);
  }
  // Log Testing
    error_log('Array of Keys'. print_r( array_keys($return_data[30]),true));
    error_log('Return Data Array: '. print_r($return_data[30],true));

    error_log('artkey:'. $return_data[30]['artkey']);
    error_log('Arttitle:'.$return_data[30]['arttitle']);
    error_log('issue:'.$return_data[30]['issue']);
    error_log('year:'.$return_data[30]['year']);
    error_log('teaser:'.$return_data[30]['teaser']);
    error_log('story:'.$return_data[30]['story']);
    error_log('images:'.$return_data[30]['images']);
    error_log('author:'.$return_data[30]['author']);
    error_log('publish:'.$return_data[30]['publish']);
    error_log('sidebardisplay:'.$return_data[30]['sidebardisplay']);
    error_log('notes:'.$return_data[30]['notes']);
    error_log('region:'.$return_data[30]['region']);
    error_log('cats:'.$return_data[30]['cats']);
error_log('Return Data Array[28]: '. print_r($return_data[28],true));
error_log('artkey[28]:'. $return_data[28]['artkey']);    
error_log('Return Data Array[29]: '. print_r($return_data[29],true));
error_log('artkey[29]:'. $return_data[29]['artkey']);
error_log('Return Data Array[30]: '. print_r($return_data[30],true));
error_log('artkey[30]:'. $return_data[30]['artkey']);
error_log('Var Dump 30:'.var_dump($return_data[30]));



    return $return_data;
}
```

The issue is found during my log test, i just check any row that i choose, in this example row 30. When i goto access the 'artkey', it is returning empty or blank.

The array keys are below, along with the print_r of the array, and what the log values returned.

```
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] Array of KeysArray
(
    [0] => artkey
    [1] => arttitle
    [2] => issue
    [3] => year
    [4] => teaser
    [5] => story
    [6] => images
    [7] => author
    [8] => publish
    [9] => sidebardisplay
    [10] => notes
    [11] => region
    [12] => cats
    [13] => editdate
)

[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] Return Data Array: Array
(
    [artkey] => 9c0e34da-e3ff-4d51-ae71-6b7003f40885
    [arttitle] => Pennsylvania Bucket List Challenge
    [issue] => Summer
    [year] => 2019
    [teaser] => <p>Take our Summer Bucket List Challenge</p>
    [story] => <p><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="/_img/articles/PA SUMMER Bucket List Challenge 2019.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></p>
    [images] => 
    [author] => Wendy 
    [publish] => Y
    [sidebardisplay] => N
    [notes] => 
    [region] => North,South,East,West
    [cats] => 
    [editdate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
)

[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] artkey:
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] Arttitle:Pennsylvania Bucket List Challenge
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] issue:Summer
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] year:2019
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] teaser:<p>Take our Summer Bucket List Challenge</p>
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] story:<p><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="/_img/articles/PA SUMMER Bucket List Challenge 2019.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></p>
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] images:
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] author:Wendy 
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] publish:Y
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] sidebardisplay:N
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] notes:
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] region:North,South,East,West
[28-Jun-2019 19:14:33 UTC] cats:
```

I am not sure whats going on with my php array, but the print_r will show a value for artkey, using any index(besides the 30 used), but it is not accessible when i goto access it by array key. Any help is appreciated, this is like the 6 importer i wrote not sure what could be happening.

**As Requested additional lines of returned data**:

```
[28-Jun-2019 19:55:53 UTC] Return Data Array[30]: Array
(
    [artkey] => 9c0e34da-e3ff-4d51-ae71-6b7003f40885
    [arttitle] => Pennsylvania Bucket List Challenge
    [issue] => Summer
    [year] => 2019
    [teaser] => <p>Take our Summer Bucket List Challenge</p>
    [story] => <p><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="/_img/articles/PA SUMMER Bucket List Challenge 2019.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></p>
    [images] => 
    [author] => Wendy 
    [publish] => Y
    [sidebardisplay] => N
    [notes] => 
    [region] => North,South,East,West
    [cats] => 
    [editdate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
)

[28-Jun-2019 19:55:53 UTC] artkey[30]:
[28-Jun-2019 19:55:53 UTC] Return Data Array[29]: Array
(
    [artkey] => 3dda11a0-37c2-4e87-b5ed-e6b2576f25ee
    [arttitle] => June 2019 Events in Pennsylvania: Historic
    [issue] => Summer
    [year] => 2019
    [teaser] => <p>If you&apos;re into history, you&apos;ll love these PA events</p>
    [story] => <h2 style="text-align: left;"><strong><span style="color: rgb(0, 168, 133); font-size: 24px;">HISTORIC EVENTS</span></strong></h2><h2 style="text-align: right;"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="/_img/articles/FIshooter.jpg" style="width: 100%;"><span style="font-size: 10px;"><em>Cook Forest French &amp; Indian War Reenactment&nbsp;</em></span></h2><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">May 25-Jul 16.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">We Can Do It! WWII Traveling Exhibit &amp; Events.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Altoona Railroaders Memorial Museum | 1300 Ninth Ave. | Altoona, PA | 814-946-0834<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/47628/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449153727505693">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 1.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Exploring the Armor.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">PA Military Museum | 51 Boal Ave. | Boalsburg, PA 16827 | 814-466-6263<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/48104/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449285435637163">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 1-2.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Korean War Traveling Memorial.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Greene County Fairgrounds | 107 Fairgrounds Road | Waynesburg, PA 15370 | 724-627-8687<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49188/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449334775601451">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 1.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Bookbinding Workshop.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">690 Sugartown Road | Malvern, PA 19355 | 610-640-2667<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49600/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449388780331772">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 6-8.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">75th Anniversary of D-Day.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Eldred World War II Museum | 201 Main St. | Eldred, PA 16731 | 814-225-2220<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49209/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449445778398824">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 7-9.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">World War II Weekend.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Mid-Atlantic Air Museum | 11 Museum Drive | Reading, PA 19605 | 610-372-7333</p><p style="text-align: left;"><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49243/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449525249979605">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 8-9.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Cook Forest French &amp; Indian War Encampment.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Cook Forest Sawmill Center for the Arts | 140-170 Theater Lane | Cooksburg, PA 16217 | 814-927-6655<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49105/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449607889995875">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 16.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">18th Century Day.</span></strong><br><span style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Brandywine Battlefield Park |1491 Baltimore Pike | Chadds Ford, PA | 610-459-3342<br></span><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/48537/"><span style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449654273444362">detail</gwmw></span></a></h2><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 22.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Traditional Cherry Fair &amp; Early American Craft Show.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Alexander Schaeffer Farm |213 S. Carpenter St. | <gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638479457839002588">Schaefferstown</gwmw>, PA 17088 | 717-949-2244</p><p style="text-align: left;"><br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49055/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449701559414876">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 22-23.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Wild West Weekend.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Old Bedford Village | 220 Sawblade Road | Bedford, PA 15522 | 814-623-1156<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49013/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449773391335356">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 28-30.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Living History Encampment &amp; Tactical Demonstrations.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638486214092116172">Solanco</gwmw> Historical Society | 1932 Robert Fulton Highway | Quarryville, PA<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49295/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638449822562246006">detail</gwmw></a></p>
    [images] => 
    [author] => W&W
    [publish] => Y
    [sidebardisplay] => N
    [notes] => 
    [region] => North,South,East,West
    [cats] => fairs-festivals,historical-sites,outdoor-recreation-outdoor-recreation
    [editdate] => 5/21/19 14:37
)

[28-Jun-2019 19:55:53 UTC] artkey[29]:
[28-Jun-2019 19:55:53 UTC] Return Data Array[28]: Array
(
    [artkey] => e55c41b3-d5ce-411a-a33e-48e46a5e55f1
    [arttitle] => June 2019 Events in Pennsylvania: Kids
    [issue] => Summer
    [year] => 2019
    [teaser] => <p>Check out these June events in PA that kids will love!</p>
    [story] => <h2><span style="font-size: 24px;"><strong><span style="color: rgb(243, 121, 52);">June Events That the Kids Will Love!</span></strong></span></h2><p style="text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: 24px;"><strong><span style="color: rgb(243, 121, 52);"><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="/_img/articles/Youth-&amp;-Family-Field-Day.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></span></strong></span><span style="font-size: 11px;"><em class="">Youth &amp; Family Field Day, Pennsylvania Lumber Museum</em></span></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 1-2, 8-9, 15-16.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Strawberry Fun Days.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Shady Brook Farm | 931 Stony Hill Road | Yardley, PA 19067 | 215-598-7240</p><p style="text-align: left;"><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49260/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638695672727548523">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 2.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Youth Fishing Derby.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Stone Hedge Golf Course | 287 German Hill Road | Factoryville, PA | 570-836-5108<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/48294/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638695760725380801">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 7-9.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Annual Snake Hunt.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">15 Club Road | Sinnemahoning, PA 15861 | 814-546-2835<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49102/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638695822865132126">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 8.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Children&apos;s Day.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Hookstown Fair Grounds, 1198 Route 168 | Hookstown, PA |<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/48274/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638695872627158580">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 8.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Youth &amp; Family Field Day.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">PA Lumber Museum | 5660 Route 6 West | Galeton, PA 16922 | 814-435-2652<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49525/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638695920597766354">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 9.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638712821698110797">Ecozone</gwmw> Discovery Room.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Pocono Environmental Education Center | 538 Emery Road | Dingmans Ferry, PA 18328 | 570-828-2319<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49555/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638695997966007842">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 18-Aug 6.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Children&apos;s Event: Stories on the Porch.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Rock Ford Plantation | 881 Rockford Road | Lancaster, PA 17602 | 717-392-7223<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49500/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638696035319999941">detail</gwmw></a></p><h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Jun 22-30.&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size: 18px;">Day Out With Thomas.</span></strong></h2><p style="text-align: left;">Strasburg Rail Road | 301 Gap Road | Ronks, PA 17572 | 717-687-7522, 866-725-9666<br><a href="https://whereandwhen.com/events/49492/"><gwmw class="ginger-module-highlighter-mistake-type-1" id="gwmw-15584638696098779512558">detail</gwmw></a></p><p style="text-align: left;"><br></p>
    [images] => 
    [author] => W&W
    [publish] => Y
    [sidebardisplay] => N
    [notes] => 
    [region] => North,South,East,West
    [cats] => kids-stuff-kids-stuff,outdoor-recreation-outdoor-recreation
    [editdate] => 5/21/19 14:38
)

[28-Jun-2019 19:55:53 UTC] artkey[28]:
```

Requested Var_dump of index 30:

```
[01-Jul-2019 13:06:51 UTC] Return Data Array[30]: Array
(
    [artkey] => 9c0e34da-e3ff-4d51-ae71-6b7003f40885
    [arttitle] => Pennsylvania Bucket List Challenge
    [issue] => Summer
    [year] => 2019
    [teaser] => <p>Take our Summer Bucket List Challenge</p>
    [story] => <p><img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="/_img/articles/PA SUMMER Bucket List Challenge 2019.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></p>
    [images] => 
    [author] => Wendy
    [publish] => Y
    [sidebardisplay] => N
    [notes] => 
    [region] => North,South,East,West
    [cats] => 
    [editdate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
)

[01-Jul-2019 13:06:51 UTC] artkey[30]:
[01-Jul-2019 13:06:51 UTC] Var Dump 30:
```

As you can see above I do not get anything returned in the var dump on the array with an index of 30, but the print_r shows data, this functional also returns all data successfully to jquery which i have create selectable rows and columns, except the story data is incomplete stopping at the quote, thats why i am in this function, attempting to save data if i can get all of it. That worked for the story but this art-key is just not accessible for some reason, not sure whats going on, i am about to start over...

[Front end return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GhgT.png)

Comment: Print the entire data for 30th row first and the from first row to 32nd row, if there are over 32 row.

Comment: sure one moment

Comment: @Nic3500 He is just pushing value at 0th index of `return_data`.

Comment: Thanks Nic, I updated my answer and retested, since $row_data wasn't being used, it didn't change the outcome of the data array. Appreciated it though. I updated the $row incrementor to be after all indexing, so it makes more sense. Still tested the code, everything is array key accessible except the artkey. Crazy.

Comment: Faham Shaikh, $data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")), the 0 in the fgetcsv results in a limitless import not only 1 row.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php . "Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.1.0 and later) the maximum line length is not limited, which is slightly slower."

Comment: I was referring to Nic's now deleted comment about the following line `$return_data[$row-1][$header[$c]] = $data[$c];` where `$row-2` was correct.

Comment: I tried your array and got the response properly for **artkey**. Please do me one more favor and var dump the output of **artkey** for 30th index.